# Double Float Bug - IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

i am trying to fix a site I am helping a friend with, and in IE it is displaying the navigation bar like it is stacking on top of each other.

Is that a part of the double float bug, I tried adding display:inline, but I still have that problem.

URL: http://www.flanels.com/RadiantecHOME.html
CSS: http://www.flanels.com/style.css`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved a local copy and modified `#top-navigation` to remove `float: left;`.

That seemed to make the top menu render the same in Firefox and IE, I have no idea what other problems it may have created however.

One of the problems I'm seeing in both IE and Firefox is that there are white vertical bars (breaks between the images) in addition to the slanted ones which I believe are part of the images.

The other thing is that if the browser is not wide enough, the top level menu does wrap as necessary.

Comment: Hey Grant...thank you for your help, removing that float, did seem to the trick. Let me tackle the white margin now. Thanks again.

Comment: should be obvious if it's on the image, if not it's an erroneous padding or a margin

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't *look* like double float to me.

From what I can see from IE dev, the <li> in IE have *neither the display nor float applied*, but it the style '#top-navigation ul li' is bound because the margin is being set to 0. I see that you're using the transition doctype so I'd start by changing that to strict if you can to get out of the difficult-to-predict quirksmode.

As smiller points out you don't need float and inline, so you should then remove one of them, then I suggest start simplifying the code to find what the conflict is.

Hopefully changing to strict will sort you out straight away.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! Let me try these out.

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

you have a float left on the containing div.